# How to update an asset (status and comment) using version one REST data API?

Tags: http-post, jersey-client, java, versionone

I'm trying to update an asset using data API like below. But I am unable to update it, it is showing an error as Bad request.

```
String updateIssueData = "{\"Attributes\":{\"Status.Name\":{\"value\":"+"Done"+",\"act\":set}}}";
invokePostMethod("rest-1.v1/Data/Defect/1538",updateIssueData);

private static String invokePostMethod(String url, String data) throws AuthenticationException, ClientHandlerException {
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(versionOneBaseURL+url);

    ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + fToken).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class,data);

    int statusCode = response.getStatus();
    System.out.println("statuscode::"+statusCode);
    return response.getEntity(String.class);
}
```

Comment: What API are you calling? What is the value of `versionOneBaseURL+url`? Find out by outputting it from your code, in case it is wrong. Is `updateIssueData` valid JSON? Maybe it is worth using JSON encoding methods rather than building this manually? Have you checked whether `fToken` is a valid token? Can you do the call successfully using `curl` before converting it to Java?

Comment: I am calling VersionOne API. versionOneBaseURL is the static which is my  account URL. the token which i am using is valid. I am able to get the Asset information using GET . But I am facing problem in updating the Asset status.